# Mathematical Codebreaking

Tags: cipher, number-sequence

I've created a [number-sequence](/questions/tagged/number-sequence) puzzle and dressed it up as a [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher) puzzle.

The following message has been intercepted. You suspect it begins with the words `THE KEY TO THIS METHOD`. Decipher the message and describe the cipher method.

```
UJIPLGEBIXBMICVKUKSETJGYXMHRAIY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer:

If we take A1Z26 of both the cipher and `UJIPLGEBIXBMICVKUKSETJGYXMHRAIY`, we get:

> 20|08|05|11|05|25|20|15|20|08|09|19|13|05|20|08|15|04
>  21|10|09|16|12|07|05|02|09|24|02|13|09|03|22|11|21|11

After the 6th column, for some entries our top number is greater than our bottom number, so we will add `26` if that is the case.

> 20|08|05|11|05|25|20|15|20|08|09|19|13|05|20|08|15|04
>  21|10|09|16|12|33|31|28|35|24|28|39|35|29|22|11|21|11

So now we make the completely arbitrary case to

> always add 26 to out bottom number **after the 16th row**.

So we change into

> 20|08|05|11|05|25|20|15|20|08|09|19|13|05|20|08|15|04
>  21|10|09|16|12|33|31|28|35|24|28|39|35|29|48|37|47|37

If we

> subtract the bottom number from the top number

we get:

> 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 22, 24, 28, 29, 32, 33

which is

> sequence [A022559](https://oeis.org/A022559) in the OEIS, or the sum of exponents in the prime-power factorization in `n!`.

Comment: This sequence is [A022559](https://oeis.org/A022559) in OEIS.

Comment: Oh. Well. I'll just go ahead and accept this answer, then. If anyone wants extra credit, they can figure out how to discover the sequence without using OEIS.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

> incrementally the key is bcefhilnpqtuwycdghkmoptvxadehin
>  Mainly found by trail and terror in a decoder
>  [image]

> [image]